# TypeError: 'Notification' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

i am new to django. i am stuck with an error "object is not iterable".
plz help me out..

//view.py

```
class NotificationList(APIView):

    def get(self,request,user_id,format=None):

        noti = Notification.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
        val=[]
        for n in noti:
            serializer = GetNotificationSerializer(n,many=True)
            in_id = serializer.data.get('interest_id') // this statement makes error
```

//serializer.py

```
class GetNotificationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
      interest_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Interest.objects.all())
      user_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())
      article_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Article.objects.all())
      status = serializers.IntegerField(required = True)
```

//model.py

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    interest_id = models.ForeignKey(Interest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article_id = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Put the error traceback

Comment: @JuanMiGabarron  my error traceback is added below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove many kwargs

```
serializer = GetNotificationSerializer(n,many=True)
#                                        ^^^
```

to

```
serializer = GetNotificationSerializer(n)
#                                     ^^^
```